# One line sed command in OS X : replace a specific line

Tags: macos, shell, sed

I want to replace the second line of my `sample.txt` file by the text `4 5 6`. In Linux I use:

```
sed '2,2c\4 5 6' sample.txt
```

However, in Mac OS X, this does not work. A workaround of this problem is to write a script where the replacing text should be kept in a newline:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e "2,2c\\
4 5 6" sample.txt
```

N.B. `-e` and double quote `" "` are important here (I don't know why).

My question is, can I merge the script into a single line command?*

This would be useful when I want to use this as a command in a program, say in Fortran.

I am not willing to install `gnu-sed`.

Let me summarize once again:

`cat sample.txt` yields

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
7 8 9
```

Using a single line command, I want to modify the file's content as:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `awk` to have a more consistent behaviour:

```
$ awk 'NR==2 {$0="4 5 6"} 1' file
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

This tells `awk` to do something just when `NR==2`, that is, when we are in line number 2. This thing is to replace the line with `4 5 6`.

Then, `1` triggers the default awk action: print the current line.

### Update

If you want to get the content from another file, just store it in a variable:

```
awk -v file_info="$(cat another_file)" 'NR==2 {$0=file_info} 1' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat f1
1 2 3
1 2 3
7 8 9
$ cat f2
hello this is me
and that is another thing
$ awk -v f="$(cat f2)" 'NR==2 {$0=f} 1' f1
1 2 3
hello this is me
and that is another thing
7 8 9
```

Comment: Though I wasn't intending to use `awk`, thanks a lot. Now it leads to the next level of my problem. What if I extract `4 5 6` from `cat sample2.txt` and put it as a replacement of the second line? Can I store the command as a variable here?

Comment: @hbaromega Sure! See my update :) `awk` is also good for this.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, works like a charm. Thinking 'awk'ward now. ;) Had a small query: You said, , **1 triggers the default awk action**. What would it intend if I had used `100` instead of `1` at the end? Apparently seems there's no change!

Comment: @hbaromega you are a fast learner and I like that you "played" with my code. `1` triggers it, as much as any True value. So you can say `1`, `100`, `"a"` or whatever that `awk` evaluates as true. There is a user here who uses `7` instead of `1`, see if you can discover him :D

Comment: probably the last bugging. ;) 

Now let me declare three variables: `a=4; b=5; c=6`. Now if I try: `awk 'NR==2 {$0="$a $b $c"} 1' sample.txt`, I don't get what I expect. What was I supposed to do?

Comment: @hbaromega You are mixing awk and Bash variables. To use a variable in awk you need to provide it with `-v`: `awk -v myvar="$a" 'BEGIN{print myvar}'`

Comment: I have just tried: `awk -v f="$(echo $a $b $c)" 'NR==2 {$0=f} 100' sample.txt`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sed script and use `c\`:

```
$ cat myscript
2c\
4 5 6
```

Then:

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed -f myscript
```

Another idea is to use `s` instead:

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed '2s/.*/4 5 6/'
```

The result is the same, but there's that extra pattern matching operation.